# Does omitting a relative pronoun change the meaning?

Tags: relative-pronouns, reduced-relative-clauses

One of my students asked me if omitting relative pronouns like "that" changes the meaning of the sentence.

Here's the issue, in the books I have read mention that in spoken English (assuming this means less formal English) "that: is omitted when it can be omitted (according to the grammar rules) and still make sense. However, when we go to school and start writing essays we are told to omit "that" if it is not needed to be more concise. So this makes the removal of the relative pronouns when not necessary more formal. Though, I do know that academic papers have a word requirement and the ideal academic paper submitted is concise and follows this rule, but we all know that we do not live in an ideal world and academic papers may be padded by the author adding or not removing unnecessary relative pronouns.

In short, is it formal or informal to remove relative pronouns in both speech and writing? Why? Where is the source? Does anyone really know?

My research yielded little but an interesting on article on Garden-path sentences via Wikipedia.

Comment: Can you give examples?

Comment: I see two different questions here: the one in the title, "Does omitting a relative pronoun change the meaning?" and repeated on the first line of the body, and then "is it formal or informal to remove relative pronouns in both speech and writing?"  Either one of these might make a good question, but you should choose one or the other.

Comment: The problem is that it's asking about _that_, which isn't really a relative pronoun, and behaves differently from _which_.

Comment: The quick answer to the question is that if grammatical deletion rules are followed, deleting a relative pronoun (or deleting _that_) does not change the meaning. Grammatical rules like _that_-deletion never change meaning -- they just allow a different way to say something.

Comment: The relative pronoun use of *that* is not the one that gets dropped, it's the connecting word: That is the one *that* I want. By the way, if your writing has a chance of later translations, or if your reader has English as second or third language, keeping *that* in is a big help in understanding.

Comment: As JL says, "that" is not a relative pronoun; it's a subordinator. Generally, though, it is more likely to be omitted in informal style, and it is also more likely to be omitted after short and common verbs than after long and less frequent ones.

Comment: "That" is listed as a relative pronoun as well as a subordinator everywhere I have looked. Where is your source that says it isn't a relative pronoun? Do you mean it's not a relative pronoun in this context?